# UWP WiFi-Direct disconnects after second incoming StreamSocketListener connection

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, wifi-direct, windows-10-iot-core

Currently i'm about to figure out, what my Problem with WiFi direct in a UWP app on Windows 10 IoT Core is. The Goal is to let a StreamSocketListener accept incoming Connections from WiFi-direct. This works well for the first Connection i make, the second request to the StreamSocketListener destroys the WiFi-direct session and it disconnects. As a side note, i have to use the legacy WiFi-Direct implementation with SSID and Passphrase. Here is some sample Code

WiFi Direct publisher

```
WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher _publisher = new WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher();
_publisher.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;

WiFiDirectConnectionListener _listener = new WiFiDirectConnectionListener();

try
{
    _listener.ConnectionRequested += OnConnectionRequested;
}
catch
{
    return;
}

_publisher.Advertisement.ListenStateDiscoverability = WiFiDirectAdvertisementListenStateDiscoverability.Normal;

_publisher.Advertisement.IsAutonomousGroupOwnerEnabled = true;
_publisher.Advertisement.LegacySettings.IsEnabled = true;

PasswordCredential creds = new PasswordCredential();
creds.Password = passphrase;
_publisher.Advertisement.LegacySettings.Passphrase = creds;
_publisher.Advertisement.LegacySettings.Ssid = ssid;

_publisher.Start();

if (_publisher.Status == WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisherStatus.Started)
{
    // OK
}
else
{
    // Error
}
```

OnConnectionRequested EventHandler

```
WiFiDirectConnectionRequest connectionRequest = connectionEventArgs.GetConnectionRequest();

WiFiDirectDevice wfdDevice = null;

try
{
    wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(connectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Id);
}
catch
{
    //
}

wfdDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged += OnConnectionStatusChanged;

listEndpointPairs = wfdDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();
```

StreamSocketListener

```
_listener = new StreamSocketListener();
await _listener.BindEndpointAsync(listEndpointPairs[0].LocalHostName, "80");
listener.ConnectionReceived += (sender, args) => ConnectionReceivedHandler(args);
```

As i said before, it works well, but i can not send a second request to the StreamSocketListener, if i do, the WiFi-direct Connection gets disconnected. Do i miss something or made a fault?

Thanks in advice

Comment: What's your windows iot core device?

Comment: A raspberrypi 3 with the latest build of windows 10 iot core.

Comment: Do you use onboard wifi or external wifi adapter?

Comment: I'm using the onboard wifi adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is solved, because MS write says in the changelog for build 17110 (current beta) the following under known issues

```
The IoTCore device has to be the connecting device – it will not work as the advertising device with another device initiating the connection.
```

So it seems that there is currently no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up multi connections on the same port number(you use "80") you may get the following exception:

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

So you need assign different ports number for every connection request.

Or you can use an empty string instead of specified number then system will assign you a unique port number. You can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocketListener_BindEndpointAsync_Windows_Networking_HostName_System_String_).

Comment: Thank you, i know this, but ist not my issue. When i set up the WiFi Direct Publisher and run the StreamSocketListener (in my case on port 80), then i can connect with a device e.g. a Smartphone via WiFi Direct by choosing the SSID and enter the passphrase. The Connection gets established and i can send a request to the StreamSocketListener. But when i try to do a second request to the StreamSocketListener, the WiFi Direct Connection gets destroyed by the app on my raspberry.

Comment: Sadly no, there is no exception or other error. I'm connecting with a phone and send a request, which gets done perfectly. Then i send another request and nothing happens, if i then look at my "OnConnectionStatusChanged" EventHandler i see that the "WiFiDirectConnectionStatus" gets disconnected.